# jquery set selected option by data-value

Tags: jquery, select

I have this select

```
<select id="myselect>
  <option value="1" data-value="rome">First option</option>
  <option value="2" data-value="paris">Second option</option>
  <option value="3" data-value="london">Third option</option>
</select>
```

And I have my ajax function that on success must set selected by data-value

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(response) {
      // response.val is paris
      $("#myselect option[data-value=" + response.val +"]").attr("selected","selected");
   ...
```

But doesn't work because of "unrecognized expression"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your id `"myselect` is missing the closing ", it should be

```
<select id="myselect">
..
</select>
```

Use

```
      $("#myselect option[data-value='" + response.val +"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k38efh2o/

Comment: Thanks, the error was in data-value='" + response.val +"'

Comment: Yes, it was the ' missing. If you're satisfied with my solution, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @james_bond Thanks